# Подматрица элемента Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Допустим есть матрица matr размером 100х100, пишем простой алогоритм на Python с двумя for для прохода по данной матрице, и нам нужно получать подматрицы размером 3х3 от элемента matr[i][j], после чего мы должны произвести некоторую операцию с подматрицей, которую получили. Вопрос такой: есть ли какойто простой способ (без пложения циклов) получить подматрицу размером 3х3, где верхний угловой элемент подматрицы matr[i][j], а нижний угловой элемент подматриы matr[i+2][j+2]? Я посмотрел и нашел, что элементы numpy имеют оси. Можно ли как то за счёт осей axis=0(ось строк) и axis=1(ось столбцов) выделить подматрицу, ограничив количество элементов по осям тремя элементами?

Comment: вы про это ? - `matr[i:i+3][j:j+3]`

Comment: @splash58 Вернее так: `matr[i:i+3,j:j+3]`

Comment: ой! да, конечно

Comment: Спасибо! Вы дали напарвление в котором думать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Numpy` вполне понимает *срезы*:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.eye(10)
for i in range(10):
    arr[i,i] += i
for i in [2,5,7]:
    print(arr[i:i+3,i:i+3])
```

Вывод:

```
[[3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 0. 5.]]

[[6. 0. 0.]
 [0. 7. 0.]
 [0. 0. 8.]]

[[ 8.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  9.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 10.]]
```